# Mercurial: diff file

Tags: netbeans, mercurial, diff

I'm actually trying something simple, but I get strange results:

I want to compare the current version of a file with a specific revision.

In NetBeans 6.9.1 I didn't find any such function. I can only call the history and then diff between successive revisions. Am I missing something?

I tried with the command line tool (Linux):
hg diff --rev 527 pom.xml

But I get:

> diff -r 1018d7890ea1 pom.xml
>
> --- /dev/null   Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970 +0000
>
> +++ b/pom.xml   Sun Jan 30 22:45:28 2011 +0000
>   @@ -0,0 +1,167 @@
>
> +

---

followed only by "+" lines.

How can I get the diff I want? How can I get this diff with NetBeans (or otherwise with another graphical diff tool)?

Comment: Looks to me like `b/pom.xml` was added sometime after revision 527 and before the current working revision.

Comment: Well, I moved the file. hg view shows: 

rename from softsmithy-parent/pom.xml
rename to pom.xml

Comment: Ah, "-g" does the trick! Now I only have to find out how to do this in NetBeans...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usage of the command-line tool looks correct.  However the output

```
--- /dev/null Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970 +0000
```

Indicates that the file you want to diff did not yet exist in the revision you chose.

Addendum:

In the comments you mention the file was renamed and you need to use -g

You can enable -g for all diffs by adding:

```
[diff]
git=1
```

to your `.hgrc` file (usually located in your home directory)

Answer (score 0):

```
hg diff -r revision1:revision2 file
```

Where revision1 and revision2 can be a tag, changeset etc.

By default, your revision2 should be "tip" (without quotes) if you want to compare a revision to the current one.